# Multiple docker container logs

Tags: go, docker

I'm trying to get the logs from multiple docker containers at once (order doesn't matter). This works as expected if `types.ContainerLogsOption.Follow` is set to false.

If `types.ContainerLogsOption.Follow` is set to true sometimes the log output get stuck after a few logs and no follow up logs are printed to stdout.

If the output doesn't get stuck it works as expected.

Additionally if I restart one or all of the containers the command doesn't exit like `docker logs -f containerName` does.

```
func (w *Whatever) Logs(options LogOptions) {
    readers := []io.Reader{}

    for _, container := range options.Containers {
        responseBody, err := w.Docker.Client.ContainerLogs(context.Background(), container, types.ContainerLogsOptions{
            ShowStdout: true,
            ShowStderr: true,
            Follow:     options.Follow,
        })
        defer responseBody.Close()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        readers = append(readers, responseBody)
    }

    // concatenate all readers to one
    multiReader := io.MultiReader(readers...)

    _, err := stdcopy.StdCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stderr, multiReader)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Basically there is no great difference in my implementation from that of `docker logs` https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/cli/command/container/logs.go, hence I'm wondering what causes this issues.

Comment: From the io.MultiReader docs: `MultiReader returns a Reader that's the logical concatenation of the provided input readers. They're read sequentially.`. You're trying to read each log to EOF before moving on to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JimB commented, that method won't work due to the operation of `io.MultiReader`. What you need to do is read from each from each response individually and combine the output. Since you're dealing with logs, it would make sense to break up the reads on newlines. `bufio.Scanner` does this for a single `io.Reader`. So one option would be to create a new type that scans multiple readers concurrently.

You could use it like this:

```
scanner := NewConcurrentScanner(readers...)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

Example implementation of a concurrent scanner:

```
// ConcurrentScanner works like io.Scanner, but with multiple io.Readers
type ConcurrentScanner struct {
    scans  chan []byte   // Scanned data from readers
    errors chan error    // Errors from readers
    done   chan struct{} // Signal that all readers have completed
    cancel func()        // Cancel all readers (stop on first error)

    data []byte // Last scanned value
    err  error
}

// NewConcurrentScanner starts scanning each reader in a separate goroutine
// and returns a *ConcurrentScanner.
func NewConcurrentScanner(readers ...io.Reader) *ConcurrentScanner {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    s := &ConcurrentScanner{
        scans:  make(chan []byte),
        errors: make(chan error),
        done:   make(chan struct{}),
        cancel: cancel,
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(readers))

    for _, reader := range readers {
        // Start a scanner for each reader in it's own goroutine.
        go func(reader io.Reader) {
            defer wg.Done()
            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)

            for scanner.Scan() {
                select {
                case s.scans <- scanner.Bytes():
                    // While there is data, send it to s.scans,
                    // this will block until Scan() is called.
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    // This fires when context is cancelled,
                    // indicating that we should exit now.
                    return
                }
            }
            if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
                select {
                case s.errors <- err:
                    // Reprort we got an error
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    // Exit now if context was cancelled, otherwise sending
                    // the error and this goroutine will never exit.
                    return
                }
            }
        }(reader)
    }

    go func() {
        // Signal that all scanners have completed
        wg.Wait()
        close(s.done)
    }()

    return s
}

func (s *ConcurrentScanner) Scan() bool {
    select {
    case s.data = <-s.scans:
        // Got data from a scanner
        return true
    case <-s.done:
        // All scanners are done, nothing to do.
    case s.err = <-s.errors:
        // One of the scanners error'd, were done.
    }
    s.cancel() // Cancel context regardless of how we exited.
    return false
}

func (s *ConcurrentScanner) Bytes() []byte {
    return s.data
}

func (s *ConcurrentScanner) Text() string {
    return string(s.data)
}

func (s *ConcurrentScanner) Err() error {
    return s.err
}
```

Here's an example of it working in the Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/EUB0K2V7iT

You can see that the concurrent scanner output is interleaved. Rather than reading all of one reader, then moving on to the next, as is seen with `io.MultiReader`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!