# Is there a way we can get docker service logs in older docker version 1.12.2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We have to use the older version of docker  1.12.2 due to some compliance issues.
But docker service logs is not introduced till docker 1.29.
The service I am starting is failing with "task: non-zero exit (1)"
and that's the extent of failure data I am able to retrieve using docker service ps

[image: trying to get the docker service logs]

Basically, I need the docker service logs on older docker version is there any way for achieving it.

I am new to docker.
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1619), you would need to use a [sidecar approach](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent) (here explained with Kubernetes, but applicable for Docker alone) in order for each of your container to send logs to the same place.

Or you can write [a program that collect logs from the containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40389137/6309) you are listing in your service.